# Camel CXF handling Bare Style WSDL

Tags: apache, apache-camel, cxf

I am stuck with a problem for quite a while. I have a bare style WSDL which I host in CXF.

Below is my sample soap request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"> 
    <ClientId>RMHP</ClientId> 
    <InputParameters></InputParameters> 
</XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest>
```

Now when I hit the service I got below fault message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unexpected element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest found.   Expected {http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService}XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below is my Web Service interface (SEI) which was generated using wsimport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="PWS_WEM_XPG_INTEGRATION" targetNamespace="http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService" xmlns:impl="http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:hc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <hc:schema xmlns:hc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">         <hc:element name="XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest" type="XpgIntegratedPaymentRequestType">              <hc:annotation>                 <hc:documentation>Root Element</hc:documentation>               </hc:annotation>            </hc:element>           <hc:complexType name="XpgIntegratedPaymentRequestType">             <hc:sequence>                   <hc:element minOccurs="0" name="ClientId" type="hc:string"/>                    <hc:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="InputParameters" type="hc:string"/>                   <hc:element minOccurs="0" name="ReceiverID" type="hc:string"/>                  <hc:element minOccurs="0" name="SecurityKey" type="hc:string"/>             </hc:sequence>          </hc:complexType>       </hc:schema>
    <hc:schema xmlns:hc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">         <hc:element name="XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse" type="XpgIntegratedPaymentResponseType">                <hc:annotation>                 <hc:documentation>Root Element</hc:documentation>               </hc:annotation>            </hc:element>           <hc:complexType name="XpgIntegratedPaymentResponseType">                <hc:sequence>                   <hc:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ResponseCode" type="hc:string"/>                  <hc:element minOccurs="0" name="ResponseMessage" type="hc:string"/>                 <hc:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorMessages" type="hc:string"/>               </hc:sequence>          </hc:complexType>       </hc:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getWemXpgPaymentRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getWemXpgPaymentRequestResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WsTransactionImlMetroSoap11">
    <wsdl:operation name="getWemXpgPaymentRequest">
      <wsdl:input message="impl:getWemXpgPaymentRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="impl:getWemXpgPaymentRequestResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WsTransactionImlMetroSoap11SoapBinding" type="impl:WsTransactionImlMetroSoap11">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getWemXpgPaymentRequest">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://test:9090/wsx/getWemXpgPaymentRequest" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WemXpgPaymentService_PWS_WEM_XPG_INTEGRATION">
    <wsdl:port name="WsTransactionImlMetroSoap11" binding="impl:WsTransactionImlMetroSoap11SoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://test:7443/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService_PWS_WEM_XPG_INTEGRATION"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Exception I get is:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest found.   Expected {http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService}XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.validatePart
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a tool to generate the SOAP request such as SoapUI. Obviously, you are not using a valid SOAP request which should look like follows (not tested):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
  soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
    <soap:Body xmlns:wem="http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService">
         <wem:XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest> 
             <wem:ClientId>RMHP</wem:ClientId> 
             <wem:InputParameters></wem:InputParameters> 
         </wem:XpgIntegratedPaymentRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note the surrounding `soap:Envelope` and `soap:Body` tags and the proper service specific namespace definition of the `wem` prefix (of course you may change the prefix name to whatever value you like).

Additional recommondation: If possible, change the default namespace in the WSDL definition of your web service. It should not contain `test:9090` but the URI of your organisation.

Comment: Hi I was able to consume  a request ithout namespace by setting following property on SEI  "@EndpointProperty(key = "soap.no.validate.parts", value = "true")".However now in the response the body is prefixed with namespace I dont want namespace to occur in soap response either.Sample soap resposne "    <ns2:RmhpHop3PaymentEffResponse xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
 
      </ns2:RmhpHop3PaymentEffResponse>
   </soap:Body>"

Comment: @user1540430 I see that you opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693238/removing-namespace-from-soap-response-camel-cxf