# Removing namespace from Soap Response Camel CXF

Tags: soap, cxf

Below is my sample Soap Response for a service hosted in camel cxf

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService"/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I don't want to generate "ns2" namespace prefix in response.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't use SOAP if you don't need validatable responses.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to drop the namespace of that element so that it is serialized as no-namespaced XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse, the common approach is to use CXF's transform feature.

see more info here: 
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html#TransformationFeature-Changinginputandoutputelementnamesandnamespaces

in your particular case, you will need the following entry

<entry key="{http://test:9090/wsx/services/WemXpgPaymentService"}XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse" 
    value="XpgIntegratedPaymentResponse"/>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Camel 2.11+ ? You can control the namespaces mapping:

Taken from:
http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html

When marshalling using JAXB or SOAP then the JAXB implementation will automatic assign namespace prefixes, such as ns2, ns3, ns4 etc. To control this mapping, Camel allows you to refer to a map which contains the desired mapping.

Notice this requires having JAXB-RI 2.1 or better (from SUN) on the classpath, as the mapping functionality is dependent on the implementation of JAXB, whether its supported.

For example in Spring XML we can define a Map with the mapping. In the mapping file below, we map SOAP to use soap as prefix. While our custom namespace "http://www.mycompany.com/foo/2" is not using any prefix.

```
<util:map id="myMap">
  <entry key="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="soap"/>
  <!-- we dont want any prefix for our namespace -->
  <entry key="http://www.mycompany.com/foo/2" value=""/>
</util:map>
```

To use this in JAXB or SOAP you refer to this map, using the namespacePrefixRef attribute as shown below. Then Camel will lookup in the Registry a java.util.Map with the id "myMap", which was what we defined above.

```
<marshal>
  <soapjaxb version="1.2" contextPath="com.mycompany.foo" namespacePrefixRef="myMap"/>
</marshal>
```

Comment: I dont want to generate any sort of namespaceSample Eg.Soap Response(Going from WEM to RMHP)
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:RmhpHop3PaymentEffResponse xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ResponseCode>-1</ResponseCode>
         <ResponseMessage>Failed</ResponseMessage>
         <ErrorMessages>RMHP Payment Effectuation xml does not comply with the RMHP Effectuation Payment Schema</ErrorMessages>
      </ns2:RmhpHop3PaymentEffResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>. I want to remove ns2="http://tempuri.org/" and namespace

Comment: Change contextPath to the package that RmhpHop3PaymentEffResponse is in and that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi  Which interceptor I shall use to remove the namespaces in SoapBody?